# Ninject - Issue on binding generic factory

Tags: ninject

I have an interface "IItemsChanger" that implements different classes.

```
public interface IItemsChanger
{
    void Change(int value)
}
```

One possible implementation is a simple class that receives an item object that can be different:

```
public class MyItemChanger : IItemChanger
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<MyItem> _items;

    public ArticoliStateChanger(IEnumerable<MyItem> items)
    {
        _items = items;
    }

    public void Change(int value)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

As you can see, the constructor has an IEnumerable of MyItem; in another implementation MyItem can be replaced with another IEnumerable.

I want the list of MyItem injected via constructor in my implementation, so i need to build a factory.
Since items can assume different type i also need to keep the factory as generic, like this:

```
public interface IItemsChangerFactory<T>
{
    IItemsChanger Create(IEnumerable<T> items);
}
```

If this makes sense, i configured Ninject like this:

```
Bind(typeof(IItemsChangerFactory<>)).ToFactory();
Bind<IItemsChanger>().To<MyItemChanger>();
```

When i try to get the implementation like this:

```
var kernel = new StandardKernel(new MyModule());
var k = kernel.Get<IItemsChangerFactory<MyItem>>();
```

I get an error:

**"Unable to cast object of type 'Castle.Proxies.ObjectProxy' to type 'MyNamespace.IItemsChangerFactory`1[MyItem]'**

How can be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

Neither Ninject nor Ninject.Extensions.Factory support this problem out of the box.
The problem is that neither Ninject nor the factory know how to map the `T` Type parameter of the `IItemsChangerFactory<T>` to a specific `IItemsChanger` implementation. That logic needs to be written by you.

Now comes the next problem. You cannot have an interface type constructors, i.E. you can't declare the constructor of `MyItemChanger` to implement `IItemsChangerFactory<MyItem>`. You can either write it compile-time-safe, but requiring some boiler plate code, i.E.:

```
class MyItemChangerFactory : IItemsChangerFactory<MyItem>
{
    public IItemsChanger Create(IEnumerable<T> items)
    {
        return new MyItemChanger(items);
    }
}
```

or you can use reflection - but lose compile time checks:

```
class ItemChangerFactory<TItem, TChanger> : IItemsChangerFactory<TItem>
{
    public IItemsChanger Create(IEnumerable<T> items)
    {
        return Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(TChanger), new object[] { items });
    }
}
```

Of course `Activator` can be replaced by delegating this to ninject by something along the lines of: `IResolutionRoot.Get(typeof(TChanger), new TypedConstructorArgument(typeof(IEnumerable<T>), items));`